# Download entire iTunes store history

Tags: itunes

I am trying to figure out how to get a single table of all my iTunes purchases since day 0 as I've realised apple having been charging me multiple times for the same item.

Edit: To confirm the way of browsing via iTunes is a bit slow when there are hundreds of records so a single dump is what I am really looking for. I remember a program I used a while ago which totalled up how much I had spent on iPhone apps but can no longer find it or work out how it did it.

Answer (score 0):

Start iTunes, choose Store, View my Account, log in, and there's a Purchase History button.

Comment: thanks but that only gives you access to individual transactions, I have a few hundred which would take a long time to go through manually, I am looking for a way to get the entire amount in one go.

Comment: It shows you 10 or 15 at a time IIRC, I'm not aware of any other way.